# What governs the Package/Deploy/Quick Deploy Solution commands

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2007

I have inherited a Sharepoint 2007 web part project, with two branches in SVN.

When I load the trunk branch SLN into VS2008 and right click on the solution I see the following commands.

```
Build Solution
Rebuild Solution
Package Solution
Deploy Solution
Quick Deploy Solution >
Retract Solution
Clean Solution
... etc.
```

But when I view an old support branch, which is a few months old I only see the following:

```
Build Solution
Rebuild Solution
Clean Solution
... etc.
```

Where do the Package/Deploy/Quick Deploy/Retract commands come from?

Comment: Curious... It turns out they are provided by VSeWSS, but I can't for the life of me see why they're available in the trunk project but no the support branch.  There are no significant differences.  So, I uninstalled VSeWSS and re-installed it and now I can see the Deploy Solution command.  Time to reboot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer to this is ridiculous.  It turns out that if you use Solution Folders to tidy up your Sharepoint application, then VSeWSS loses the Package, Deploy, etc. commands.

Bad Microsoft!  In your bed!